# How to assign a javascript variable or an array with php variable

Tags: php, javascript, datepicker

My question may be simple or something similar to other question, But i am just unable to accomplish this task.

I am trying to **disable some dates in datepicker dynamically**.
I am just running a query which gives a list of holidays.

```
$date[]=$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$day; // array
```

and i am using implode so that i can have **comma** separated list

```
$abc=implode(',',$date);
```

so $abc contains dates.

Here is my **javascript**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
//var Alldays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"];
/* var disable= '<?php echo $info; ?>'; // yyyy/MM/dd*/
var disableDates="<?php =$abc; ?>"; 

//var disableDays = ["Saturday", "Sunday"];
//var disableDates = ["2013/02/26", "2013/02/28"];
alert (disableDates);
function ShowDisableDates(date) {
ymd = date.getFullYear() + "/" + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
//alert(ymd);
//ymd= ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/" + date.getFullYear();
day = new Date(ymd).getDay();
if ($.inArray(ymd, disableDates) < 0 ) {
return [true, "enabled", "Book Now"];
} else {
return [false, "disabled", "Sold Out"];
}
}
$(function() {
$("#datepicker").datepicker({beforeShowDay:ShowDisableDates});
});
</script>
```

But i am not able to access the dates from **$abc** to javascript.

If i declare them as static as

```
var disableDates = ["2013/02/26", "2013/02/28"];
```

It works fine

Please guide me to solve this, Thanks

Comment: Consider `json_encode()`, and turn on error_reporting. Your output syntax is wrong. It's `<?=` not `<?php =`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `$abc` is an array:

```
var disableDates = <?= json_encode($abc); ?>;
```

Comment: You would want to remove the `"`